# Navigation bar with active Tab without additional modules

Tags: reactjs

The question is rather simple and is not specifically connected to navigation bars, it's just a good example..

I want to create simple navigation bar with active tab highlighting by using 'active' class. Currently I have two components: NavBar and NavItem. On tab click, I would like to make it active and make sure all others become inactive.

What would be the easiest solution to this? How to reset multiple NavItems inside NavBar to default inactive state without one that was clicked?

---

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';

import NavItem from './NavItem';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.menuItems = [
            { name: 'HOME', url: '#' },
            { name: 'NEWS', url: '#' },
            { name: 'CONTACT', url: '#' }
    ];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    CHOOSE:
                    {this.menuItems.map( (item,i) => <NavItem key={i} data={item} /> )}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

---

NavItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class NavItem extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            active: false
        }
    }

    handleOnClick() {
        this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
    }

    render() {
            let item = this.props.data;
            return <li><a href={item.url} className={this.state.active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={ (e) => this.handleOnClick(e) }>{item.name}</a></li>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the NavBar component state, you can save which tab is currently active and also make the method to handle the onClick inside the NavBar and pass it down to NavItem as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see benefit of putting list item in a different component. In fact you would end up setting `active` class on 1 list item due to each item is a separate component.

Simplest thing could be to put list in the same component and pass an index in click function.

```
{this.menuItems.map((item,i) => <li><a href={item.url} className={this.state.activeItem == i ? 'active' : ''} onClick = {(e) => this.handleOnClick(e,i) }>{item.name}</a></li> )}
```

now click function would look something like -

```
handleOnClick = (event, index) => {
    this.setState({activeItem: index});
  }
```

So your component would look like

```
import React from 'react';

import NavItem from './NavItem';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.menuItems = [
      {
        name: 'HOME',
        url: '#'
      }, {
        name: 'NEWS',
        url: '#'
      }, {
        name: 'CONTACT',
        url: '#'
      }
    ];

    this.state = {
      activeItem: 0
    }
  }

  handleOnClick = (event, index) => {
    this.setState({activeItem: index});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
          CHOOSE: {this
            .menuItems
            .map((item, i) => <li>
              <a
                href={item.url}
                className={this.state.activeItem == i
                ? 'active'
                : ''}
                onClick=
                {(e) => this.handleOnClick(e,i) }>{item.name}</a>
            </li>)}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

I've setup item at 0 index default active but you could change it according to the needs.

Comment: nice, although this solution constrain his implementation to only 1 item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the React Docs article, [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) , has been written exactly to the use-case you have been demonstrated.

You are managing the `isActive` state inside each component in isolation. Each Instance of `NavItem` can't know, and should not know, what is the state of the other instances of `NavItem`

So ... lift your state up! Manage the information about active/inactive bars, inside `Navbar`, and control your multiple `NavItem` instances through props.

It should look like this:

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';

import NavItem from './NavItem';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menuItems: [
        { name: 'HOME', url: '#', isActive: true },
        { name: 'NEWS', url: '#', isActive: false },
        { name: 'CONTACT', url: '#', isActive: false }
      ]
    };
    this.menuItems = [];
  }
  onNavItemClick = itemName => {
    const nextMenuItems = this.state.menuItems.map(item => {
      if (item.name === itemName) {
        return { ...item, isActive: true };
      }
      return { ...item, isActive: false };
    });
    this.setState({
      menuItems: nextMenuItems
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
          CHOOSE:
          {this.state.menuItems.map((item, i) => (
            <NavItem
              key={item.name}
              name={item.name}
              isActive={item.isActive}
              onClick={this.onNavItemClick}
              url={item.url}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

NavItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class NavItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    console.log()
    this.onClickFunction = () => this.props.onClick(this.props.name);
  }
  render() {
    let item = this.props.data;
    return (
      <li className={this.props.isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
        <a
          href={this.props.url}
          onClick={this.onClickFunction}
        >
          {this.props.name}``
        </a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `<NavLink to="" activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} />` component as links/tabs (from 'react-router-dom')

Answer (score 0):

**LiranC**, **Infinity**, thanks for help and examples, I think I got it.
I knew it would end with lifting state to NavBar, only wasn't so sure how to make a reference to specific element..

I want to have only one element active at the time, with list item component for future purposes, so I mixed it and came up with such code. Looking forward to any further optimization advices.

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';

import NavItem from './NavItem';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.menuItems = [
            { name: 'HOME', url: '#' },
            { name: 'NEWS', url: '#' },
            { name: 'CONTACT', url: '#' }
        ];

        this.state = {
            activeItem: null
        }
    }

    handleOnClick = (e,i) => {
        this.setState({activeItem: i});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    CHOOSE:
                    {this.menuItems.map( (item,i) => 
                        <NavItem
                            key={i}
                            idn={i}
                            data={item}
                            isActive={this.state.activeItem == i ? true : false}
                            onClick={this.handleOnClick} />
                    )}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

NavItem.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class NavItem extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let item = this.props.data;

        return (
            <li>
                <a 
                    href={item.url}
                    className={this.props.isActive ? 'active' : ''}
                    onClick={ (e) => this.props.onClick(e, this.props.idn) }>{item.name}
                </a>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```